No option to return to the main site after tenant-level search in SharePoint
I've recently changed the search scope in one of my SharePoint sites to tenant level. Now, whenever a user performs a search from this site, the results are displayed from the entire tenant, which is working as expected. However, I've encountered an issue where there is no clear option for users to return to the main site from which they initiated the search. Once they are on the search results page, there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to navigate back to the original site.
Is there a way to add a navigation option or link that allows users to easily return to the main site after viewing the search results? Any suggestions or solutions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

It's possible I'm misunderstanding you, but isn't there a back arrow button on the search box? Please describe your problem in a little clearer or take a screenshot of your problem. Thank you for your time and efforts in advance.

@KarleyZhou-MSFT Thanks for your comment. Yes, I can see the back arrow button on the search box that I had missed earlier. This is taking me back to the original page from where I had initiated the search. Apart from this, is there any other OOTB option available to setup such navigation or link on the page which is more prominent?

It would be just back arrow in search bar. Or back arrow in browser. Yes, UX is not the best. But even searching throug Org you are still at your site. So the orter option is just update Url by removing "_layouts/15/search.aspx?q=wdfgwersf"

